# Convex optimization under asymmetric loss in infinite dimensional space

Tags: pr.probability, banach-spaces, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, linear-programming

The following problem is common in financial economics
$$ \min_{m \in L^2} \mathbb{E}[ \phi(y(\theta)-m)] \quad \text{s.t. } \mathbb{E}[ mx ]= q $$
That is, given a random variable $y(\theta)$ ($\theta$ is some parameter vector), a random vector $x$ and a known vector $q$, find $m \in L^2$ which is closest to $y(\theta)$ under the convex loss function $\phi$.

Variations of this problem usually consider changing the loss function $\phi$. When $\phi(x) =x^2$ it is well known that the solution above is $m = y(\theta) + \lambda'x$, where $\lambda$ can be determined from the constraint. Such problems are conveniently solved using the dual representation using the results of Borwein & Lewis (1991). For my research I need to solve a similar problem with asymmetric loss function $\phi(x) = x(\tau - I(x<0))$ (well known from quantile regression).

However, following the standard approach of solving the dual problem seems to lead to a problem that is not well defined. Hence my question: is it possible to solve this optimization problem using duality? If not, are there any other results in the literature that allow one to solve a problem like this?

Below I describe my reasoning for the dual problem. Using the results of Borwein & Lewis (1991) leads to the dual problem
\begin{align}
\max_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lambda^\top q - \mathbb{E}[\rho_\tau^*(\lambda^\top x)], \label{eq:dual} \\
\rho_\tau^*(z) = \sup_{w \in L_2} zw - \rho_\tau(y(\theta)-w) \label{eq:conj}
\end{align}
For suitable $z$ in the domain of the convex conjugate $\rho_\tau^*$ I obtain $\rho_\tau^*(z) = zy(\theta)$ and using this in the objection function renders
\begin{equation*}
\max_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n} \lambda^\top q - \lambda ^\top\mathbb{E}[ x y ]
\end{equation*}
This of course, doesn't have a well defined solution. Hence it seems that the dual problem is not equal to the primal problem (potentially since the loss function is not strictly convex).

Comment: There's no "law" that says you can't solve the primal (original) problem.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone are there common techniques to solve the primal problem? Most of the approaches in the literature I'm aware of always use the dual representation.

Comment: Enter the primal problem in an optimization solver, or a front-end to an optimization solver.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone thanks a lot for your advice! Are these primal optimization solvers also capable of solving infinite dimensional problems like the one above? Additionally, do you think an analytic solution can be found?

Comment: You will have to discretize to convert to finite dimensional. The solvers work with a finite number of variables and finite number of constraints.